# Limit of a monotone function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f\colon [a,b] \to[a,b]$ be a non-decreasing function in a sense that $f(x)\leq f(y)$ whenever $x\leq y$. Although there may be several fixpoints of $f$, [at least one does always exist and there exists a greatest fixpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem), let us call it $x^*$. I wonder whether it holds that $x^* = \lim\limits_n f^n(b)$. Clearly, if $f$ is continuous this would be true, but I wonder whether this fact can be established purely based on the monotonicity of $f$.

Comment: Indeed, if $S$ is the set of fixpoints and $s = \sup S$, then either $s$ is a fixpoint itself (which means that it is the greatest fixpoint), $f(s) < s$ (which implies that each fixpoint is smaller then $s$, hence $\sup S < s$; contradiction) or $f(s) > s$ (which implies that there is a fixpoint greater than $s$, by monotonicity; contradiction).

Comment: @GitGud: Here's a direct proof: Suppose not, then there is an increasing sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of fixed points which converges to some $x^* \in [a,b]$ with $x^* \ge$ all fixed points. If $x^*=b$ or $f(x^*)=b$ then we must have $f(b)=b$, so $x^*<b$ and $f(x^*)<b$. Let $\max \{x^*, f(x^*) \} < c < b$. Then $f|_{[c,b]} : [c, b] \to [c, b]$ is nondecreasing, so there's a fixed point in the interval $[c,b]$, contradicting maximality of $x^*$.

Comment: Normally, non-decreasing means $f(x) \geq f(y)$ when $x \geq y$, i.e. it implies monotonicity.

Comment: @GitGud: regarding your last comment. K-T itself says that the set of fixpoint is a complete lattice, so there exists the greatest fixpoint - I don't really see why do you need to show this *using* K-T. Anyways, existence of the greatest fixpoint is something I knew about. My OP contains quite a different question, though - do you know how to approach it?

Comment: @Ilya As I thought one of the hypothesis was wrong, I just thought it was important to mention. Regarding your last comment, you misunderstood me, but nevermind, it's irrelevant now.

Comment: @Ilya Nope, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is no, and the example is given as follows. Let $a = -1$ and $b = 1$, with 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
  \frac12x^2,& \text{ if }x>0
  \\
  -\frac12,&\text{ if }x\leq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
We have that $x^* = -\frac12$ whereas $f^n(b) \geq 0$ for all $n $ and also $\lim_n f^n(b) = 0$. Hence, motonocity is not enough by itself and some continuity assumption is needed.